# undefined reference to main issue (using arduino, RaspberryPi, GCC)

Tags: c, gcc, arduino, serial-port, raspberry-pi

I'm making a program(**C language**) on **RaspberryPi** 
My program get a data from **Arduino** by Serial communication

Source Code here :

```
#ifdef RaspberryPi 

//include system librarys
#include <stdio.h> //for printf
#include <stdint.h> //uint8_t definitions
#include <stdlib.h> //for exit(int);
#include <string.h> //for errno
#include <errno.h> //error output

//wiring Pi
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <wiringSerial.h>

char device[]= "/dev/ttyACM0";

// filedescriptor
int fd;
unsigned long baud = 9600;
unsigned long time=0;

//prototypes

void loop(void);
void setup(void);

void setup(){

  printf("%s \n", "Raspberry Startup!");
  fflush(stdout);

  //get filedescriptor
  if ((fd = serialOpen (device, baud)) < 0){
      fprintf (stderr, "Unable to open serial device: %s\n", strerror (errno)) ;
    exit(1); //error
  }

  //setup GPIO in wiringPi mode
  if (wiringPiSetup () == -1){
    fprintf (stdout, "Unable to start wiringPi: %s\n", strerror (errno)) ;
    exit(1); //error
  }

}

void loop(){
  // Pong every 3 seconds
  if(millis()-time>=3000){
    serialPuts (fd, "Received\n");
    time=millis();
  }

  // read signal
  if(serialDataAvail (fd)){
    char newChar = serialGetchar (fd);
    printf("%c", newChar);
 if((int)newChar >= 1){
  system("raspistill -o image.jpg");
  system("convert image.jpg -threshold 20% imagebw.jpg");
  system("tesseract imagebw.jpg imageocr");
  system("cat imageocr.txt");
 }
    fflush(stdout);
  }

}

int main(void){
  setup();
  while(1) loop();
  return 0;
}

#endif //#ifdef RaspberryPi
```

Before I put

```
system("convert image.jpg -threshold 20% imagebw.jpg");
system("tesseract imagebw.jpg imageocr");
system("cat imageocr.txt");
```

this code, it worked well
But, It does not work even if I delete it.
I found following error on my compiler(**GCC**)

```
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gneabihf/4.9/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/ort1.o:In function '_start':/build/glibc-mqlSLF/glibc-2.19/csu/../ports/sysdeps/arm/start.S:119 : undefined reference to 'main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit sutatus
```

And I used following two command

```
sudo gcc test.c -o hello -lwiringPi -DRaspberryPi <br>
sudo gcc test.c -o hello -lwiringPi -DRaspberryPi -nostartfiles
```

Can anybody help me with this issue?

Comment: The signature for main should be `int main(void)`. Probably *not* the issue, but you know... better write standard conformant code.

Comment: @StoryTeller Thanks for it. I'll edit.

Comment: Why use `sudo` when building? Why calling `gcc` twice?

Comment: Check again that you wrote `-DRaspberryPi` correctly in the console, a typo is the most likely cause of your error: in fact it suffices to omit it to reproduce your error message. Having said this, *Arduino* is not *Java*, you should move the **implementation code** into a proper `.cpp` file and leave only *declarations* in the **header**.